# Grouping Varying Size of Lists in a Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to group all the lists in a tuple, based on the last element in each list and also count the mount of times the last element occurred. However the challenge I am finding is that all the lists in the tuple can be of different sizes.

Eg input

```
[['aa', 'b'], ['bb', 'c'], ['cc', 'b'], ['dd','ee','a'], ['ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'a']]
```

And I am trying to get the output to be

```
('a', 2, [('dd','ee'),('ff', 'gg', 'hh')]), ( 'b', 2, [('aa'), ('cc')]), ( 'c', 1, [('bb')])
```

Finally I want to then go ahead and convert it to a panda-dataframe format. If anyone can help/guide, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: are `a`/`b`/`c` in your desired output string literals or what?

Comment: Did you mean to put a, b, and c in quotes?

Comment: @bstrauch24 Sorry yes, just amended to quotes

Answer (score 1):

Readable version

```
mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(-1)) # sort by last element

result = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=operator.itemgetter(-1)):
    # remove last element from each sublist:
    g = [tuple(sublist[:-1]) for sublist in g]
    result.append((k, len(g), g))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without importing a library

```
list = [['aa', 'b'], ['bb', 'c'], ['cc', 'b'], ['dd','ee','a'], ['ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'a']]

instances = {}
for sublist in list:
    leading_elements, last_element = sublist[:-1], sublist[-1]
    instances.setdefault(last_element, [])
    instances[last_element].append(tuple(leading_elements))

result = tuple()
for key, val in instances.items():
    result += (key, len(val), val)
```

Comment: it works, but why? Also, it won't matter for this small list, but for a big iterable this would make a huge dict, while `itertools.groupby` only keeps a single element in memory.

Answer (score -1):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [['aa', 'b'], ['bb', 'c'], ['cc', 'b'], ['dd','ee','a'], ['ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'a']]
>>>
>>> f = lambda sl: sl[-1]
>>> res = [(k, [tuple(sl[:-1]) for sl in v]) for k,v in groupby(sorted(l, key=f), f)]
>>> res = [(k, len(v), v) for k,v in res]
>>> print(res)
[('a', 2, [('dd', 'ee'), ('ff', 'gg', 'hh')]), ('b', 2, [('aa',), ('cc',)]), ('c', 1, [('bb',)])]
```

Comment: This example is wrong - I run the code but didn't get the result as in the answer - something didn't copy correctly. I tried both python 2.7 and 3.6

Comment: @nosklo. Sorry.. should be fixed now